# Will off loading tasks to background threads improve overall performance in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, macos, thread-safety

While using XCode Time Profile, I see that most of my function calls are being performed in the main thread. Since they're not UI related, I want to move them to the background thread. Will offloading these tasks to the background thread improve the performance of my app or would it still be the same. I know that at least it'd benefit updating the UI. How to exactly measure the performance of an app using Instruments, which profiling module should I use?

Thanks

Comment: It *may* increase performance; it will almost certainly improve responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Offloading tasks that don't require a main thread is the way to go. Your main thread only deals with the action that demand user attention or are related to UI actions.

I don't know what do you mean by performance when you talk about delegating background threads. Indeed, you are putting forward a better UI/UX but performance as such can't only be uplifted through threads.

I recommend you profile your application and see what objects are you creating?

-Monitor any leaks.

-Consider doing a time profiling.

-Check if your I/O and CPU activities are optimum.

These will surely help you nail down and performance related issues. 
(NB: Your 5% of time should also go to profiling your app.)

Answer (score 0):

If you took , off loading task in background thread, the main benefit will be that **it will remove code dependency** that means your UI related task will not be dependent on non-UI related task that will increase you'r app's performance.
And This whole process is called **concurrency programming** in iOS which you can refer from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

For instance, if I am downloading a file from the internet and I want to update the user on the progress of the download, I will run the download in the priority default queue and update the UI in the main queue asynchronously.

```
  // Doing something on the main thread

dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    // Perform long running process

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI

    });
}); 

// Continue doing other stuff on the 
// main thread while process is running.
```

For profiling you can refer this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeProfile.html